# how close Navigate File Structure dialog (Ctrl+F12) with emacs keymap in the intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use the emacs keymap, and I use the Navigate File structure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) dialog extensively.  When using the emacs keymap, when I want to dismiss this dialog I hit the Esc key.  This displays additional options at the bottom.  It reads 'Prefix Key Pressed.' along with a bunch of options.  One option is 'Escape (Escape)', which I would guess dismisses the dialog.  However, the dialog continues to display.  How can I use the keyboard to dismiss this dialog while using the emacs keymap?

- OS: windows 10 ,windows 7
- IntelliJ IDEA version: 2017.2.5
- Build #IU-172.4343.14, built on September 26, 2017

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a known issue with File Structure popup: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93152. Other popups are closed properly with double Esc.